# Java reflection to initialize Kotlin object fails when object contains 'init'

Tags: java, android, kotlin, reflection

I have some Java code that uses reflection to create a new object. The new object is an object I coded in Kotlin. The code works fine, unless in my Kotlin class I use `init` to try and initialize some variables.

eg:

```
private BaseClass constructViewHolderClass(View itemView, int viewType) {
    View itemView = ...

    Class<? extends BaseClass> baseClass = ChildBaseClass.class;

    Constructor<? extends BaseClass> ctor;

    ctor = baseClass.getConstructor(View.class);

    return (BaseClass) ctor.newInstance(new Object[]{itemView});
}
```

Kotlin class that works:

```
class ChildBaseClass(itemView: View) : BaseClass(itemView) {

    var imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view)
    var circularProgressDrawable = CircularProgressDrawable(itemView.context)
}
```

Kotlin class that does NOT work:

```
class ChildBaseClass(itemView: View) : BaseClass(itemView) {

    var imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view)
    var circularProgressDrawable = CircularProgressDrawable(itemView.context)

    init {
        circularProgressDrawable.strokeWidth = 5f
        circularProgressDrawable.centerRadius = 30f
        circularProgressDrawable.start()
    }
}
```

The exception thrown is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

Stacktrace:

```
Process: com.project.acme, PID: 12668
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.project.acme.extlibs.myrecyclerview.MYRecyclerViewAdapter.constructViewHolderClass(MYRecyclerViewAdapter.java:844)
    at com.project.acme.extlibs.myrecyclerview.MYRecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MYRecyclerViewAdapter.java:830)
    at com.project.acme.extlibs.myrecyclerview.MYRecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MYRecyclerViewAdapter.java:16)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:625)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
```

Comment: Can you provide a full stack trace of an exception?

Comment: added the stacktrace

Comment: Does this line: `at com.project.acme.extlibs.myrecyclerview.MYRecyclerViewAdapter.constructViewHolderClass(MYRecyclerViewAdapter.java:844)`
correspond to `ctor.newInstance(new Object[]{itemView})`?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the code snippet above. `constructViewHolderClass` is the method that uses reflection to try and initialize the baseclass.

Comment: Well my question is if it fails at `baseClass.getConstructor` or at `ctor.newInstance`

Comment: Sorry, fails at `ctor.newInstance`

Comment: Out of curiosity, removing `circularProgressDrawable.start()` changes anything?

Comment: Removing `circularProgressDrawable.start()` doesn't help.

Comment: `InvocationTargetException` is a wrapper around the actual, underlying `Exception`, which would really help in diagnosing this. Unfortunately, that stack is so deep, it's cutting off before it gets to the `Caused by`s. You could use a `try-catch(InvocationTargetException e)` around your code, and see what `e.getCause()` and `e.getCause().getMessage()` return.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I found the issue. Added to solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry everyone, I left out one line in the `init` function that is actually causing the issue:

`circularProgressDrawable.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilter(itemView.context.resources.getColor(R.color.text_default), BlendMode.SRC_IN)`

Not sure why this is causing an issue, but will look into it.

Sorry for wasting anyone's time.

Comment: May I suggest you delete the original question and then post the new question if you still have an issue?